QSAN XCubeNAS 8112 unable to join into Windows 2016 domain
QSAN XCubeNAS 8112 unable to join into Windows 2016 domain.  Where as in same domain able to join other devices except this above NAS box.  To check compatibility we created test domain with Win 2016 and Win 2019 and able to join.  No issues with compatibility.
Getting the below error.
Failed to join AD Server
ads_sasl_spnego_bind:Kinit succeeded but SPNEGO bind with Kerberos failed for ldap/domainname.com - user (device host name) realm (Domainname.com) : invalid credentials.
Any help here.

This is QSAN support team, thanks for sharing this problem detailed information. Normally, we will create a support ticket to help you to solve this problem. But not sure have you forwarded this problem for us before. If yes, can you confirm the support ticket no is "Q202408130352972"? We will reopen this support ticket to follow up of this AD join issue. /Arthur

Appreciate the QSAN Team responding to this query.  Yes this is the ticket no. Q202408130352972.  Since you guys have communicated that nothing to do from QSAN hence started working towards domain controller and in this process reached this platform.  Appreciate if you can reopen the ticket and support us.
